# git clone --recursive git@github.com:orybkin/video-gcp.git returning an error

Tags: git

I am trying to run this code https://github.com/orybkin/video-gcp.
It requires me to first clone the GitHub repository

```
git clone --recursive git@github.com:orybkin/video-gcp.git
cd video-gcp

virtualenv -p $(which python3) ./venv
source ./venv/bin/activate
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
python3 setup.py develop
```

I am unable to do so as the command `git clone --recursive git@github.com:orybkin/video-gcp.git` gives me an error message

```
(base) PS C:\Users\kong> git clone --recursive git@github.com:orybkin/video-gcp.git
Cloning into 'video-gcp'...
The authenticity of host 'github.com (140.82.121.3)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:+DiY3wvvV6TuJJhbpZisF/zLDA0zPMSvHdkr4UvCOqU.
This key is not known by any other names
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

How should I resolve this?

@Sercan: Thank you. I tried but still got several errors. I was not able to clone the blox and gym-miniworld folders. I have the same git version as you.

```
(base) PS C:\Users\kong> git clone --recursive git://github.com/orybkin/video-gcp.git
Cloning into 'video-gcp'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 192, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (176/176), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (149/149), done.
remote: Total 192 (delta 21), reused 162 (delta 13), pack-reused 16 eceiving objects:  96% (185/192), 24.05 MiB | 8.01 MiB/s
Receiving objects: 100% (192/192), 25.96 MiB | 8.11 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (21/21), done.
Submodule 'blox' (git@github.com:orybkin/blox-nn.git) registered for path 'blox'
Submodule 'gym-miniworld' (git@github.com:kpertsch/gym-miniworld) registered for path 'gym-miniworld'
Cloning into 'C:/Users/kong/video-gcp/blox'...
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
fatal: clone of 'git@github.com:orybkin/blox-nn.git' into submodule path 'C:/Users/kong/video-gcp/blox' failed
Failed to clone 'blox'. Retry scheduled
Cloning into 'C:/Users/kong/video-gcp/gym-miniworld'...
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
fatal: clone of 'git@github.com:kpertsch/gym-miniworld' into submodule path 'C:/Users/kong/video-gcp/gym-miniworld' failed
Failed to clone 'gym-miniworld'. Retry scheduled
Cloning into 'C:/Users/kong/video-gcp/blox'...
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
fatal: clone of 'git@github.com:orybkin/blox-nn.git' into submodule path 'C:/Users/kong/video-gcp/blox' failed
Failed to clone 'blox' a second time, aborting
(humoro) PS C:\Users\kong> git --version
git version 2.31.1.windows.1
(humoro) PS C:\Users\kong>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cloned the project you specified with submodules using the following command:

```
git clone --recursive git://github.com/orybkin/video-gcp.git
```

The **.gitmodules** file needs to be updated for the cloning to be successful:

```
[submodule "blox"]
    path = blox
    url = git://github.com/orybkin/blox-nn.git
[submodule "gym-miniworld"]
    path = gym-miniworld
    url = git://github.com/kpertsch/gym-miniworld.git
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried but still got several errors. I was not able to clone the blox and gym-miniworld folders. I have updated my post. Were you able to clone them?

Comment: I think fork the project and clone the project after editing the .gitmodules file.

Comment: Thank you! Fork -> edit the .gitmodules file -> clone from my repo worked perfectly!

Comment: I'm glad it worked. There is a difference in the use of the `--recursive` flag between Git versions. I guess this is one of the causes of the problem.